# How to update value in each iteration in jmeter instead of each occurrence?

Tags: csv, jmeter, beanshell, blazemeter

I have an scenario in which there are 5 times existence of same email id in one flow(scenario). I want to take a data from csv file which should be same for entire flow. By default jmeter updates the value on each occurrence, but i need the value to be updated in each iteration. Can this be done in jmeter?
I trying to take same value for an iteration in jmeter from created csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the file is only opened once, and `each thread will use a different line from the file.`

Means , JMeter thread will use a different value for each iteration not for each occurrence.

In below example , "Thread Group" has "two samplers" and each sample reads data from the same "CSV data file". Means Thread Group has "TWO OCCURRENCES" of the "name", but JMeter uses same value ("jmeter", is a value in CSV file) for each iteration (means each occurrence has same name (jmeter) ). Check below images for more details

**Thread Group:**

[image]

**Results Tree:**

[image]

**Csv File:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, confusion is clear.
Do with any case can i change the value in each occurrence?